# regular expression like linux command

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

as it should be a regular expression to do this? like to be a regular expression to do this?

my string:

value11-ttable-mtest-xtest2

and i want have:

```
(main value) value11

(-t value) = table 
(-m value) = test
(-x value) = test2
```

and maybe add more -y parameters

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's easier to solve without regular expressions. One suggestion here:

```
$values = array();
foreach (explode('-', 'value11-ttable-mtest-xtest2') as $index => $string) {
    if ($index == 0) {
        $values['main'] = $string;
    } else {
        $option = substr($string, 0, 1);
        $value = substr($string, 1);
        $values[$option] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: hank you so much work, I had not thought of a simple explode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking here. You could get the result you describe using

```
explode('-', 'value11-ttable-mtest-xtest2');
```

Why do you want to use a ergular expression?

Answer (score 0):

This regex : `^([^-]*)(?:-([^-])([^-]+))*$` with `preg_match_all` should work.

Where :

- `([^-]*)` : captures 0 to n times any character but -
- `-([^-])` : captures first letter after -
- `([^-]+)` : capture 1 to n times any character but -